# node cluster with socket.io and expressjs

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, cluster-computing, node-cluster

Here's my server code:

I'm trying to use cluster with socket.io and expressjs. I'm testing this on my quad core desktop.

```
var cluster = require('cluster')
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork()
  }

  console.log(new Date());
}
else {
  // get required modules
  var connect = require('connect');
  var express = require('express');
  var mongo = require('mongodb');
  var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
  var server;
  var redis = require('redis');
  var http = require('http');

  // create server object
  app = exports.module = express();


  function configureServer() {
    //configure environments
    app.configure('production', function() {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    //configure server instance
    app.configure(function() {
      app.use(express.compress())
      // set jade as default view engine
      app.set('view engine', 'jade');
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.cookieParser("refdgfd"));

      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(app.router);
      // use express logger
    });

    loadModules();
  }

  var server = http.createServer(app).listen(80);

  socket = require('socket.io').listen(server);

  var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis')
    , pub    = redis.createClient()
    , sub    = redis.createClient()
    , client = redis.createClient();
  socket.set('store', new RedisStore({
    redisPub : pub
  , redisSub : sub
  , redisClient : client
  }));

  socket.configure(function() {
    socket.set('log level', 1);
    socket.set('transports', ['websocket']);
  });

  configureServer();
}
```

Is there anything that stands out to be really wrong?

The logs indicate that everything happens 4 times. Which seems correctly. But my socket.io's channel users also indicate that whenever I connect to a page, I connect 4 times, (create 4 user sockets). That seems wrong. How do I fix it and are there other things wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Duplicated messages in number of cores. I've tried all the combinations out there and no luck. Have you found any fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

At this moment `socket.io` has no full support for `node.js cluster`. It works fine for me with `websocket` transport, but `xhr-pooling` fails. You can reed more in this issues: [#939](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/939), [#917](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/917). The problem is the `xhr-pooling` request can get into the thread different from the one which it was originally authorized.

Comment: Thanks, i'm actually only using websocket, neglected to include that in my code, I've updated it now. xhr-polling has some problems other than the ones mentioned here and websocket is generally reliable through SSL.